# How to remove Meta Tracker integration in Nautilus

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, tracker

I installed [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/) to index some of my files, however it seems that this application integrated well in Nautilus and I want to remove this integration as unnecessary.

Problem is that I use Nautilus search bar to search for filenames, so when I type some filename I'm looking for, this task is processed through Tracker and I get totally irrelevant results.

How can I remove Tracker integration from Nautilus, without removing Tracker itself?

---

First comment on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker (after "How to disable tracker globally" - which I don't want) describes this same problem

I also posted this on Tracker mailing-list linking to this question, but no one replied.

Comment: I expected at least confirmation that this is not possible. I removed Tracker from my system and installed Recoll. There were no issues on Tracker removal